How do I assign specific Subnets to a VPC in CDK typescript
New to AWS CDK Typescript and thought this would be easy BUT I'm struggling to get this to work. I want to assign 3 subnets - 2 Public, 1 Private to a VPC at startup:
Public01: 10.10.5.0/24
Public02: 10.10.10.0/24
Private01: 10.10.15.0/24
Anyone know how this can be done? Currently I get 10.10.0.0/24, 10.10.1.0/24 and 10.10.2.0/24 - which i do not want:
const myvpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'MyVPC', {
  maxAzs: 1,
  natGateways: 0,
  cidr: '10.10.0.0/16',
  subnetConfiguration: [
    {
      cidrMask: 24,
      name: 'Outside',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    },
    {
      cidrMask: 24,
      name: 'Management',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
    },
    {
      cidrMask: 24,
      name: 'Inside',
      subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
    },
  ],
});


Does this answer your question? CDK Create Subnets on VPC

No, not what I’m looking  to do. I am actively trying to assign specific subnets. Thanks anyway

I think you can still create subnet objects for specific existing subnets using ec2.Subnet.fromSubnetId(this, 'public-subnet-1', 'subnet-1234345') and assign them to your VPC like the example in the URL.

They don't want to use existing subents, and it's not possible to create a subnet outside of a VPC, so none of that applies.

What you're asking is not possible with the Vpc construct. You will have to use the L1 CfnVPC and create your own Subnet instances.

@gshpychka thanks, you're right. I was able to do it using L1 constructs.
